# Зависимость смысла от знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация, смысл

Выясните, какая ошибка, приводящая к искажению смысла, допущена при расстановке знаков препинания в каждом нижеуказанном случае.

А. Анатомическо-арифметический парадокс.
Пальцев у него двадцать пять: на каждой руке десять, на ногах всего двадцать.

Б. Рогатый скот?!
В нашем колхозе много рогатого скота: лошадей, свиней.

В. Охотники и рябчики.
Рябчики говорят: охотники любят дремать на деревьях.

Г. Солнце блеяло?!
Когда солнце село с блеянием и ревом, прошло стадо.

Д. Скамейка ждала подругу?
Ольга сидела на скамейке, которая находилась в сквере и ждала подругу.

Е. Кто же пришел?
– Все ли здесь?
– Нет. Здесь только Ваня, Миша, Маша, Коля, Костя, Дима, Настя, еще не пришли.

Answer (score 1):

Я не стала закрывать вопрос — можно ведь и просто поулыбаться, а можно и немного поразмыслить, потренироваться.

Правильно:
Б. В нашем колхозе много рогатого скота, лошадей, свиней.
В. Рябчики, говорят охотники, любят дремать на деревьях.
Г. Когда солнце село, с блеянием и ревом прошло стадо.
Д. Ольга сидела на скамейке, которая находилась в сквере, и ждала подругу.
Е. — Все ли здесь?
— Нет. Здесь только Ваня. Миша, Маша, Коля, Костя, Дима, Настя еще не пришли.
(Плюс четыре дополнительных варианта с передвижкой запятой. Последний: *Дима, Настя еще не пришли*.)

Меня заинтересовало предложение *А*.
Пальцев у него двадцать: пять на каждой руке, десять на ногах, всего — двадцать.
Пальцев у него двадцать: пять на каждой руке, десять на ногах (всего — двадцать).
Пальцев у него двадцать. Пять на каждой руке, десять на ногах, всего — двадцать.
Пальцев у него двадцать: пять на каждой руке, десять на ногах. Всего — двадцать.

Плюс эти же предложения без тире. Или есть еще варианты?
*Казнить нельзя помиловать,* однако.

Comment: Попрактиковаться, конечно, можно, учитывая что в Б у вас ошибка ;)

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, какая?

Comment: Хотя, виноват, у вас все верно, все равно)

Comment: Я бы просто иначе поправил. В вашем колхозе много скота: лошадей, свиней.

Comment: Иначе — нельзя, вопрос ведь только о расстановке знаков (без какого-либо изничтожения текста), а не о правке предложения. Я не зря написала про казнить-помиловать.